# Linux on a Chromebook

Tags: boot, chromebook

I've managed to jump through the hoops to be able to boot from a *USB drive*, and go through the installation process for *Linux* on my Chromebook, a **Lenovo 100S**.

For some reason though, after completing the installation, I reboot my computer and *SeaBios* says `"No bootable device."`

If I wait around, then it tries to boot into *ChromeOS* but it of course can't since I replaced it with *Linux*.

I've tried using *Fedora 24* and *Ubuntu 16.04*, and neither worked after the installation, though both work perfectly fine from the live USB.

I'm not sure where to begin debugging this, so any help would be appreciated. I'm using the *[RW_LEGACY ROM from John Lewis](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used it myself but this script lets you specify the default boot target:

https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript

Comment: Yeah, I got some help from MrChromeBox on Google+. Turns out I had to use that script with the BOOT_STUB ROM. [Here's the thread](https://plus.google.com/117017390975797938973/posts/EU65D6DyU2r) in case anyone else wants to check it out. I was able to boot normally with the RW_LEGACY ROM, but I unfortunately had no sound. With BOOT_STUB, sound is working fine, but I'm still having issues with bluetooth, as you can see from the thread.